# ListComprehension but different order

Tags: haskell

I would like to know if there is a difference between these to definitions.

```
[(x,y)| x<-[1..10000], x=2000,y<-[1..100], odd y]
[(x,y)| x<-[1..10000],y<-[1..100], x=2000, odd y]
```

Both will generate same list of tuples.
But if our compiler doesn't do any optimization. 
How can i find out which one is faster. 
In both case `x<-[1..10000]` will give us a list from `[1,2.. 20000] since x==2000.`
In what order will the y value be evaluated?

Comment: To Haskell they are equivlaent: both produce a parse error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things are executed left-to-right.  Think of it as nested loops.  So in the first one the test of x is executed 10000 times, and in the second it's executed 1000000 times.

Moving the condition outwards to speed up the execution is called "filter promotion"; a term coined by David Turner (ca 1980).

Comment: in the second it's executed 1000000 times?
how can that be true?
we only have 10 000 element in the list

Comment: There 10000 values for x, and for each of these there are 100 values for y.  So there are 1000000 million (x,y) values.

Comment: you mean 1000000 (x,y)

Comment: Do you know what map (:)  does?

Comment: I do.  But it doesn't do anything interesting.